# How to config extracted text from array

Tags: javascript, json, loops

I extract data to text from this array

> format_array = ["SEO", "PR", "Review", "Ebook", ...]

(Have more varables, so I must use "forEach")

I use this loop but result is not beautiful

> undefinedSEO, PR, Review, Ebook,

I want to plain data, and not have "," at the last, like this:

> SEO, PR, Review, Ebook

Code I use:

> format_array = ["SEO", "PR", "Review", "Ebook", ...];

```
  var format;
  format_array.forEach(function(entry) {
    format += entry + ", "
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use [`.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
var format_array = ["SEO", "PR", "Review", "Ebook", "More", "And", "More"];

console.log(format_array.join(', '))
```

Comment: I have more variables, so I must use "forEach"
Sorry, I edited my question

Comment: @cmdntd if you have more variables, this would still work. could you specify more on your case?